# do you have to restart services after running sysctl -p?

Tags: rhel, sysctl

I'm increasing the watch limit on my RHEL 7 server and I'd like my changes to take effect without having to reboot.  I've updated the /etc/sysctl.conf file so that the changes will be permanent.  If I run `sysctl -p` after updating the systcl.conf file, will the new watch limits be applied to services that are currently running or will they have to be restarted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man` page:

> `-p`       Load in sysctl settings from the file(s) specified or /etc/sysctl.conf if none given.  Specifying - as filename means reading data from standard input.

YES. the new watch limits are applied to services that are currently running